# functions library in drools

Tags: java, eclipse, drools

I have below two files in the same folder.RuleFile.drl is the rules library and Sample.drl is the functions library. I am getting error mentioned below when I try to execute the rules.

I am not sure what am I missing and how to resolve this error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

File: RuleFile.drl

```
package com.sample
rule "A stand alone rule"
    when
        //conditions
    then
        myFunction(5);
end
```

File: Sample.drl

```
package com.sample
function int myFunction(int val){
    return val;
}
```

I am getting the below error message in the eclipse and also when I run the code.

```
The method myFunction(int) is undefined for the type Rule_A_stand_alone_rule_3e142aa079ee4a37b0fb21f9e9d9c0da
```

Java Code:

```
public class DroolsTest {
    private static final String RULES_CHANGE_SET = "RuleConfig.xml";
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // load up the knowledge base
            KnowledgeBase kbase = readKnowledgeBase();
            StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
            KnowledgeRuntimeLogger logger = KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory.newFileLogger(ksession, "test");
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static KnowledgeBase readKnowledgeBase() throws Exception {
        KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
        kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(RULES_CHANGE_SET), ResourceType.CHANGE_SET);
        KnowledgeBuilderErrors errors = kbuilder.getErrors();
        if (errors.size() > 0) {
            for (KnowledgeBuilderError error: errors) {
                System.err.println(error);
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse knowledge.");
        }
        KnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
        kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
        return kbase;
    } 
}
```

RuleConfig.xml

```
 <change-set xmlns='http://drools.org/drools-5.0/change-set'
             xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
             xs:schemaLocation='http://drools.org/drools-5.0/change-set http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossrules/trunk/drools-api/src/main/resources/change-set-1.0.0.xsd' >
  <add>
       <resource source='classpath:RuleFile.drl' type='DRL' />
       <resource source='classpath:Sample.drl' type='DRL' />
   </add>
 </change-set>
```

Comment: When you build the knowledge base, do you see an error? Or is the error only seen within Eclipse?

Comment: I don't see an issue during ant build. However the .drl files are not needed for build. I believe these are used during run time. I am trying to execute the rules...

Comment: I mean at runtime, when the code runs through the steps to compile the knowledge base. If that's when you're seeing the error, then please provide the code that you use to build the knowledge base from these two files.

Comment: I got the same error when I try to execute the rules.

Comment: And would you mind posting the contents of "RuleConfig.xml"? I think that's the last piece of the puzzle to see what you're doing.

Comment: link to build.xml file http://pastebin.com/ZkPifP2h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drools need that rules are ordered: so in your xml file change the order, your function myFunction() is not actually read yet by drools when it starts parsing RuleFile.drl: I think this is why you get the error. Sample.drl must be parsed before RuleFile.drl and the order in your XML file is important.

Comment: @Srik Make a commons.drl file where it defines shared rules and facts, and make it be parsed first. See it like dependency management between modules in a maven project.